# Puppet - file search & list

Tags: puppet

I would like to know if it is possible to perform a file search using puppet which collects all the files of a certain type. I have seen an interesting puppet attribute named **tidy** [More info here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/type.html#tidy) which is used to remove all files of a certain type. I would like to be able to just collect the names of those files (not delete them). I know that I can create my own puppet fact with python code to do that, but efficiency is also important. Is it possible to use tidy just for collecting (and avoid deleting) or a similar puppet attribute to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your intention with the list of files you could potentially generate through this technique? I'm wondering if you couldn't use tidy with a noop to get close to what you're looking for, but still... how would you envision using this?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. My intention is to have a sort of report of all these files of the same type that are in every puppet node. Just a list. I don't want to remove anything. I will investigate if tidy + noop gives me what I need.

Comment: I've never used the `tidy` resource, but I'll give it a shot in my own work. Off topic by a bit, but are you using something like [Puppet Board](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppetboard) to display your reports, or are you querying PuppetDB in another way?

Comment: A custom or external fact is indeed going to be the best bet here. As for efficiency, that will be up to the code itself. Anecdote: I had a fact once that hashed all installed rpms with their installed versions. First version took 90 seconds on older hardware, but then I managed to get it down to under ten.

Comment: Provided `find` is available, this could be a trivial shell script. Can you provide any more detail @JohnAntoin?

Comment: @mburling I'm indeed using Puppet Board. I'm looking for efficent ways of listing all git repos in every puppet node.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I think I will do that (custom fact). It was one of my options when I came here, but as I have discovered tidy I though that if I was able to deactivate the tidy delete feature it would be more efficient than running external code. I'm really interested about the fact that you have wrote a script that hashed all installed rpms with their version. To be honest, I have think about having that in the future. If you still have the script, will you share it? I would add to it a comparisson with trusted rpm hashed and report if a difference is discovered. Thanks!